# pillar.get and defaults.get returns null value with nested dicts in Salt

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

In my pillar, I'm attempting to populate a value from a nested dict in `defaults.yaml`:

```
rippled:
  version: 1.2.2
```

```
tags:
  - {{ salt['defaults.get']('rippled:version') }}
```

I can access the top dict via the CLI, however it doesn't return the nested value, and returns `null` in the config which I'm building:

```
salt-call defaults.get rippled
local:
    ----------
    rippled:
        ----------
        config:
            ----------
        hash:
            5zf863d39b135dce1e3a15e1b62e096df03de5c7a0e3a4b879f02b7207cf0c04
        service:
            False
        version:
            1.2.2

salt-call defaults.get rippled:version
local:
```

I get similar results with `pillar.get`, however there I can get the nested dict value from the CLI, but also get `null` in the file:

```
rippled:
  config:
    version: 1.2.2

  tags:
    - {{ salt['pillar.get']('rippled:config:version') }}

salt-call pillar.get rippled:config:version
local:
    1.2.2
```

results in file:

```
"tags": [
  null
```

Comment: appears to be a bug since it works with non-nested dicts

Comment: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/52690

Comment: That last example looks like you're querying a pillar item from the same file defining that item. I don't think that will work; the contents of the {{  }} jinja block get rendered before the rest of the pillar is seen.